# Hot to set minimum_match on terms filter for custom_filters_score using tire?

Tags: elasticsearch, tire

I'm using tire gem and found very interesting feature - custom_filters_score.
Using custom_filters_score I can present the search results sorted by score, which is dynamically calculated.

My (almost ;-)) only problem is following query:

```
days = ['2013-01-17', '2013-01-18', '2013-01-19']

Tire.search 'hotels' do
  query do
    custom_filters_score do

      query { string '*' }

      filter do
        filter :match_all
        script "doc['my_score'].value"
      end

      filter do
        filter :terms, 'prices.date' => days#, :minimum_match => days.size
        script "100 + doc['my_score'].value"
      end

      score_mode 'multiply'
    end
  end
end
```

Every hotel can have a collection of prices for specified days. Above query should give me **first** all hotels which have specified prices for every requested day (see 'days' array). And then I should get other hotels, which don't need to have all prices specified.

At the moment it is not working correctly. I get first hotels which have prices only for some requested days. 
I think that something like minimum_match could help here, the problem is when I set that option the query is not working at all. I'm getting: QueryParsingException, filter does not support [minimum_match]

Could you please give me some tips what options I have to get it working using tire / elasticsearch?

I'm afraid this is just first problem I will have...

Prices collection can have following structure - we can have different prices for 2 adults and for 1 adult for the same day:

```
{
  "id":1,
  "name":"Hotel Zamkowy",
  "city":"Słupsk",
  "my_score":5,
  "prices":[
    {
      "allocation":1,
      "price":79,
      "adults":2,
      "children":0,
      "date":"2013-01-17"
    },
    {
      "allocation":1,
      "price":87,
      "adults":2,
      "children":0,
      "date":"2013-01-18"
    },
    {
      "allocation":1,
      "price":98,
      "adults":2,
      "children":0,
      "date":"2013-01-19"
    },
    {
      "allocation":1,
      "price":75,
      "adults":2,
      "children":0,
      "date":"2013-01-20"
    },
    {
      "allocation":1,
      "price":55,
      "adults":1,
      "children":0,
      "date":"2013-01-16"
    },
    {
      "allocation":1,
      "price":59,
      "adults":1,
      "children":0,
      "date":"2013-01-17"
    },
    {
      "allocation":1,
      "price":67,
      "adults":1,
      "children":0,
      "date":"2013-01-18"
    },
    {
      "allocation":1,
      "price":78,
      "adults":1,
      "children":0,
      "date":"2013-01-19"
    },
    {
      "allocation":0,
      "price":55,
      "adults":1,
      "children":0,
      "date":"2013-01-20"
    }
  ]
}
```

The allocation number is important as well, it basically tells how many available rooms we have for specific day and for specific adults / children combination.

How to query elasticsearch to give me **first** hotels which have allocation and price for requested days?

I hope it makes sense ;)

Thanks,
Marek

Answer (score 1):

You should use a :range instead of a :term. Something similiar to this:

:range=> { 'prices.date' => { :gte => lower_price , :lt => higher_price }}